# Looking for synonymous expressions for - to throw someone away like a used toothpick

Tags: slang, idiom-requests, colloquialisms

In my native (Georgian) language we have this colloquial saying - **throw someone away like an eaten apple**, meaning- *to get rid of someone after having taken advantage of him/her in a dishonest way*.
I have come across a few such sayings in English as well, like- *to throw someone away like an old rug* or *used toothpick* or *spit someone out like a cherry stone,* etc.

I have a question, are there any other such sayings and which one is used more frequently in English?

Comment: _Throw_ doesn't have the sense of _discard_ in English; you have to use _throw away._

Comment: It's _toothpick_. With a P, not an ST. _Toothstick_ is too hard to say and never made it.

Comment: As far as I am aware, there is probably no "set-phrase or saying - people often invent a simile. The general usage is probably most common in written/literary English - less so in spoken. Of the ones that come to mind, "He threw/cast/tossed her aside like an old rag." is relatively common.

Comment: @JohnLawler -- I have heard "like an old toothbrush" once or twice.  And likely "toothstick" is used to mean "toothbrush" in some cultures.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

> Cast aside like an old glove
>
> Discarded like trash
>
> Tossed aside like an old sweater

There are probably more commonly used expressions, but I think you could get creative with this one if you wanted to!

See:
https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/cast-something-or-someone-aside